# Gradle - won't allow maxHeapSize to be set?

Tags: groovy, junit, gradle

```
task test(type: Test, overwrite: true, dependsOn: [setupUser]) {
    maxHeapSize "3000m"
    allJvmArgs "-Xmx3000m"
}
```

Error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.
> Could not find method allJvmArgs() for arguments [-Xmx3000m] on root project 'myproject'.
```

No matter what I try, I get heap issues when I run `gradle test`. I'm using `1.0-milestone-9`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line (`allJvmArgs "-Xmx3000m"`) is incorrect syntax which explains why Gradle complains. The first line (`maxHeapSize "3000m"`) is fine and I'd be surprised if it didn't work. `"3000m"` might be too high a value though and could lead to an error when creating the JVM. In any case, look for the following debug output (`-d`):

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ProcessBuilderFactory] creating process builder for Gradle Worker 1
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ProcessBuilderFactory] in directory /xxx
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ProcessBuilderFactory] with argument#0 = -Xmx300m
...
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Started Gradle Worker 1.
```

Comment: I'll try lowering the memory requested. From this article, though, it looks like the syntax is correct. http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Comment: The syntax would be correct for `jvmArgs`, but not for `allJvmArgs`. The latter is rarely used directly and hence doesn't offer the same convenience methods. I can't see the incorrect syntax used anywhere on the page you linked to. Anyway, the correct approach to solve your problem is `maxHeapSize`. As shown above, it's easy to verify that the memory settings are forwarded correctly.