# Gradle JavaExec Task, How to use allJvmArgs property

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

According to Java Exec [allJvmArgs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:allJvmArgs) property javadoc, allJvmArgs is

```
List<String> allJvmArgs

The full set of arguments to use to launch the JVM for the process. This includes arguments to define system properties, the minimum/maximum heap size, and the bootstrap classpath.
```

I am trying to use this property unsuccessfully. Below is my attemps.

Example Java Code.
    //src/main/java/com/examples

```
package com.examples;

public class AllJvmArgumentsInJavaExecBug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello From Java");
    }

}


// File: build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

task(runJavaExecNormal, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.examples.AllJvmArgumentsInJavaExecBug'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

}


task(runJavaExecArgumentSetExample1, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.examples.AllJvmArgumentsInJavaExecBug'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    allJvmArgs = [ '-Xms10240m', '-Xmx20280m']

}

task(runJavaExecArgumentSetExample2, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.examples.AllJvmArgumentsInJavaExecBug'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    List<String> argumentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    argumentList.add('-Xms10240m')
    argumentList.add('-Xmx20280m')
    allJvmArgs = argumentList
}
```

I get following error.

```
P:\github\gradleJavaExecAllJvmArgs>gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'P:\github\gradleJavaExecAllJvmArgs\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleJavaExecAllJvmArgs'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.733 secs
```

I am unable to use this property. 
I can use maxHeapSize = "2g" as pointed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794829/gradle-wont-allow-maxheapsize-to-be-set/).
I would like to use it to set minumum heap size.

Following is [github project](https://github.com/ati-ozgur/gradleJavaExecAllJvmArgs) which recreates this situation.

Comment: The preferred way to set the min heap size is with `minHeapSize = "128m"`. To learn which configuration options are available for a particular task, check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the source from `org.gradle.process.internal.JavaExecHandleBuilder` contains:

```
public void setAllJvmArgs(Iterable<?> arguments) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

you should be able to use `jvmArgs` instead of `allJvmArgs`.